# Mobile app with couchbase (REST services)

Tags: jquery-mobile, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I'm creating a mobile app using cordova.

I decided to use Couchbase to store datas; but I can't figure out the difference from couchbase (server) and couchbase lite(/or mobile).

I have downloaded the couchbase server on my system, but how to connect it with my app?

Can I develop a mobile app only with couchbase server and rest calls?

Can I use N1QL to 'query' the server with .NET also using phonegap? (because couchbase mobile doesn't support n1ql).

I could just call a rest web service done with .NET or maybe JAVA but so is it needed to add couchbase mobile to the app?

Comment: And why in the Couchbase mobile doc (https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.4/installation/phonegap/index.html) there is a getting started with Phonegap but then the tutorials you have to chose between IOS or Android? I'm building crossplatform, i'm not using native languages.

Comment: To answer the comment about a PhoneGap tutorial, Couchbase Mobile works on many platforms.  We're not a huge company and don't have the resources to create versions of our content specific to every platform.

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase Mobile means the combined stack of Couchbase Server, Sync Gateway, and Couchbase Lite.  Couchbase Server is a backend NoSQL enterprise database.  Couchbase Lite is used embedded on a device.  You glue them together with Sync Gateway.

Using Couchbase Server directly via REST calls isn't likely to work well.  Server is built with different expectations about network latency and reliability.  For example, you typically update a document using a CAS (compare and swap) approach.  This doesn't work well if you have an unreliable network.  (That's one very crude example.)  Technically you can develop an app this way, but you're asking for big headaches.  (This is true with any database not built for mobile.)

The Couchbase Mobile stack was developed to deal with all the problems faced in using an unreliable network.  With the current version (1.4) of Couchbase Mobile you can do querying with map/reduce.  This is already powerful.  Stay tuned for support of new query capabilities in the upcoming 2.0 release.

N1QL is great, and it would be nice to have it available on mobile now.  However, unless you really just can't get along without it, you should really work with the standard Couchbase Mobile stack.

For PhoneGap support, take a look at the information in the plugin GitHub repo: https://github.com/couchbaselabs/Couchbase-Lite-PhoneGap-Plugin